# python argparse with mandatory input file argument

Tags: python, argparse

How to add a mandatory option to the parser with prefix -i or --input to specify the input file to the script?

The provided value should be placed into the infile variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distilling from the documentation, a minimalistic answer would be

```
import argparse

#Create the parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Does some stuff with an input file.')

#add the argument
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', dest='infile',  type=file, required=True,
                metavar='INPUT_FILE', help='The input file to the script.')

#parse and assign to the variable
args = parser.parse_args()
infile=args.infile
```

Be aware that if the specified file does not exist, the parser will throw an IOError. removing the type=file parameter will default to reading a string and will let you handle the file operations on the parameter later on.